# Override style of app-header-layout's shadow DOM

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

I'm having a bit of an awkward problem. I have the following template:

```
<app-header-layout>
  <app-header>
    <app-toolbar> ... </app-toolbar>
  </app-header>

  <main> ... </main>
</app-header-layout>
```

Let's say the `app-header` has a height of 200px. When the page is loaded, the `#contentContainer` of the `app-header-layout` shadow DOM will automatically be assigned a `padding-top` of 200px (based on the current height of `app-header`).

Then I have a media query for print which removes the `app-header`:

```
@media only print {
  app-header {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

So when I open the print dialog, the `app-header` isn't rendered, but `#contentContainer` still has a `padding-top` of 200px. I know `app-header-layout` has a [`resetLayout()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-header-layout#method-resetLayout) method, but even if it were possible to reset the layout after the print dialog is open, I'd still want it to go back to its original value once I close the dialog.

Now my question is: can I force the `padding-top` of `#contentContainer` to be 0 when the media query for print is active? In other words, how can I override the style of `#contentContainer` in the shadow DOM of `app-header-layout`? I tried `app-header-layout::shadow #contentContainer` but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple to showcase this in a fiddle. I don't how it handles print media queries. I'll give it a try and update my question if I can easily get something working to show you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could also try is adding or removing css class with a bit of javascript, something like:

```
changeContainerPadding: function() {
    this.$.contentContainer.classList.add('zeroPadding');
    this.$.contentContainer.classList.remove('normalPadding');
}
```

Not really an elegant solution, but this approach sometimes help me in desperate times :)

Comment: I don't think this would work in my case, because I'd have to run this when the @media queries for print are active. Best solution here would involve CSS only. I ended up using a layout for print only with position absolute that "sits" on top of the `contentContainer`'s padding. Thanks for your help anyway, this might be helpful in another scenario.